# I am trying to get the opening times for a museum but it opens differently in different months. New to javascript

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to javascript but I am trying to use a switch statement to get the month then inside use an if else too tell me if it is between two times. I think it could be the "&&" inbetween the hours aswell.

```
var hour = new Date().getHour()
var opening

  switch (new Date().getMonth()) {
    case 0:
      if hour => 10 && hour <= 17 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }

    case 1:
      if hour => 10 && hour <= 17 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
    case 2:
      if hour => 10 && hour <= 17 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
    case 3:
      if hour => 9 && hour <= 18 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
    case 4:
       if hour => 9 && hour <= 18 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
      case 5:
       if hour => 9 && hour <= 19 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
      case 6:
       if hour => 9 && hour <= 19 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
      case 7:
       if hour => 9 && hour <= 19 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
      case 8:
       if hour => 9 && hour <= 18 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
      case 9:
       if hour => 10 && hour <= 17 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
      case 10:
       if hour => 10 && hour <= 17 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }
      case 11:
       if hour => 10 && hour <= 17 {
        opening = "Open"
      }
      else {
        opening = "Closed"
      }

      document.getElementById("open").innerHTML = opening;




  }
```

Comment: You should go back to learn the basics of javascript, because there are way too many errors in your code, this almost looks like pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing parenthesis for the condition, and also the final statement should be outside the switch block, and also `getHours` not `getHour`.

And here is a shorter script:

```
var hour = new Date().getHours()
var open = true;

switch (new Date().getMonth()) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
      if(hour < 10 || hour > 17) open = false;
      break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 8:
      if(hour < 9 || hour > 18) open = false;
      break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
      if(hour < 9 || hour > 19) open = false;
      break;
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11:
      if(hour < 10 || hour > 17) open = false;
 }

 document.getElementById("open").innerHTML = open ? "Open" : "Closed";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following errors in your code:

- `if` needs parentheses around the condition: `if(… && …)`
- The last statement should be *after* the closing brace
- Each case should be terminated by a `break` statement if you don’t want to run the rest of the switch block.

In the last point, I suspect that you may have a VBA background, where each case is *exclusive*. In JavaScript, once you’re in, you stay in until either the end of the `switch` or you exit it with a `break` statement.

I have a simplified version of your code as follows:

```
var hour = new Date().getHour()
var opening

switch (new Date().getMonth()) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        opening = (hour => 10 && hour <= 17) ? "Open" : "Closed";
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        opening = (hour => 9 && hour <= 18) ? "Open" : "Closed";
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
        opening = (hour => 9 && hour <= 19) ? "Open" : "Closed";
        break;
    case 8:
        opening = (hour => 9 && hour <= 18) ? "Open" : "Closed";
        break;
    case 9:
    case 10:
    case 11:
        opening = (hour => 10 && hour <= 17) ? "Open" : "Closed";
        break;
}

document.getElementById("open").innerHTML = opening;
```

Features:

- Where multiple cases have the same outcome, I have removed the code entirely, and allowed the case to fall through to the next one, taking advantage of the point mentioned above.
- You can simplify some `if` values using the conditional operator `… ? … : …`, which means `test ? plan A : plan B`, similar to `iif` in VBA or to `IF` in Excel.

In the above code, I have put the test inside parentheses in the conditional operator, but they are *not* required in this form. They *are* for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can compact the code quite a bit if you put the opening times into an array, then just get the applicable times for the current month, e.g.

```js
var openingHours = [[10,17],[10,17],[10,17],  // Jan Feb Mar
                    [ 9,18],[ 9,18],[ 9,19],  // Apr May Jun
                    [ 9,19],[ 9,19],[ 9,18],  // Jul Aug Sep
                    [10,17],[10,17],[10,17]]; // Oct Nov Dec
       
var date  = new Date();
var hour  = date.getHours();
var month = date.getMonth();
var state = 'Closed';

if (openingHours[month][0] <= hour && openingHours[month][1] > hour) {
  state = 'Open'
}

document.getElementById('shopState').innerHTML = state + 
  ' (it\'s ' + (hour%12||12) + ':' + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
  ' ' + (hour<12?'am':'pm') + ')';
```

```html
<div>We are currently <span id="shopState"></span></div>
```

This approach can also work with date ranges, but months are neat. :-)

Note that the test for closing time is `>` assuming that in, say, January, you close at 17:00. If the test is `>=` then it won't show closed until 18:00.